# Enabling GPU + CPU Render simultaneously

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, osx

I note [here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/cycles-apple-metal-device-feedback/21868/11), that preliminary support for Metal/Apple Silicon on M1/M1-Pro/M1-Max/M1-Ultra, should provide the ability to render with CPU, GPU or both.

I'm on a stable release, not a beta, on version `Version 3.1.2 (3.1.2 2022-04-01)`.

I have GPU compute enabled in settings, however, I only see the option in Cycles render settings to enable CPU OR GPU, not both.

Any ideas?

Also, which type of workloads does CPU + GPU together improve?

Comment: If you select the CPU and GPU in the User Preferences, then switching Cycles to GPU means you're using GPU and CPU. This came in (I don't know exactly) Blender 2.8x something, if I remember correctly. However, personally I disable the CPU in the preferences on my computer at home, because the CPU slows down the render, the GPU alone is faster. My computer at work however is faster if I enable both.

Comment: I believe that the Metal support that Apple has provided Blender for 3.1 is still a work in progress in the sense that some features are missing and CPU/GPU render is one of them. Otherwise, what @GordonBrinkmann wrote.

Comment: OK thanks both. I noticed in the beta previews on YouTube CPU+GPU was supported, however maybe it was removed from the stable release.

Comment: I don't really know, but if your only indicator to suspect it's been removed is the fact that the Cycles render settings only show either CPU or GPU, that doesn't say anything. Because as mentioned before, the GPU setting means use everything that's enabled in the preferences, and if the CPU is enabled there they will both be used simultaneously. And if the PC version only shows GPU but uses both, why should it show both in the Mac version?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - yep that makes sense thank you

Comment: Can you run with GPU compute and see if Activity Monitor shows near 100% on both CPU and GPU?  I don't have an Mx machine to test...

Comment: you want me to test if a render with GPU only also spikes the CPU?